# Using html helpers in Razor web helper with Telerik is giving Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

I am trying to create my View using Razor Engine .My ~View/Web.config file already have namespaces

[image]

but it gives me error:

> system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper does not contain definition of
>   telerik and no extension method.....

[image]

when i run this page ..it runs properly and all component of telerik extention works fine.

Comment: So far looks good. Have you tried common manipulation: clean solution, restart VS, rebuild?

Comment: I have tried everything ....It runs fine and when i tried to develop more pages, Intellisense support in Visual Studio also not supporting..